# Circular reference error for enum disappears when renaming enum case parameter

Tags: swift, xcode

I've got a enum with an indirect case as shown below. The compiler raises a "Circular reference error" related to that enum.

The point is, as soon a I rename the parameter `lastAction` for the `catchError` case (for example to `lastaction` or `lastAction1` - or anything else) the error disappears and the build succeeds.

Why is that? I tried out everything - cleaning the build folder, deleting derived data, setting the compile mode from "incremental2 to "whole", even installing xCode from scratch...

Any ideas? ... I don't want to rename that parameter!!!

```
enum Action {
    case add
    case edit(UUID)
    case close

    indirect case catchError(Error, lastAction: Action)
    case cancelLastAction
    case retryLastAction
}
```

P.S.: I have another - similar enum with amongst others excactly the same `catchError` case (just with another action type). This one works, even with the parameter named `lastAction`...

Comment: Hmm that's odd... might be a compiler bug. Are there any other things called `lastAction` in your workspace?

Comment: Yes, but definitely in different name spaces. The error occurred today - yesterday it worked. I even tried to keep the name for this enum and rename the other one, but that did not work. Are there any other Xcode related cache areas I can delete? Or any other compiler settings that might help?

Comment: When in doubt, delete derived data :D Not sure about anything else.

Comment: I already did that several times. It did not help unfortunately.

Comment: File an issue, I think this is a bug.